# Querying DATE in MySQL using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, pdo

I am updating my code to use PHP PDO... I came across an sql query

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS number_of_item FROM ".$db_table_prefix."item_table 
WHERE id > 0 
    AND date_visited BETWEEN 
    CAST('$start_date' AS DATE ) 
    AND CAST('$end_date' AS DATE )";
```

which i replace with this

```
$this->sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS number_of_items FROM item_table
                      WHERE id > :id AND date_visited
                      BETWEEN CAST(:start_date AS DATE )
                      AND CAST(:end_date AS DATE )";
        $this->prepare($this->sql);
        $this->bind(':id', 0);
        $this->bind(':start_date', $date_start);
        $this->bind(':end_date', $date_end);

        $this->execute();

        sizeof($this->multiple_fetch()) > 0 ? $this->result_set = $this->multiple_fetch() : $this->result_set = 404;

        return $this->result_set;
```

I have entries in my database that meet all the criteria but my new code is giving this as a result

```
array (size=1)   0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'number_of_items' => int 0
```

My questions, is there something i am doing wrong? Is there a better way or different way of using the

> CAST(... AS DATE)

in PDO?

> UPDATE

Here is what my bind method look like

```
function bind($placeholder, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = \PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = \PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = \PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = \PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($placeholder, $value, $type);
    }
```

My $date_start and date_end values are 2016-11-01 and 2016-11-30 respectively. I have about 101 dummy entries in my db (item_table) with date_visited as 2016-11-18

Comment: What is exactly inside `$start_date` and `$end_date` ? Also in you `bind()` method, are you passing them as `string` ?

Comment: are `$start_date` and `$end_date` `DateTime` objects or `string`? Have you tried `$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date))`(and same for `$end_date`) and then pass them to the query without `CAST`?

Comment: @EhsanT Yes, I have done the `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date))` and i am still getting same result... The  `$start_date` and `$end_date` are both string...

Comment: can you create a simple [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ? When you query directly in `mysql` do you fetch records?

Comment: @EhsanT You've been really helpful... I finally figured it out, using you suggestion above. Before, i was doing the `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date))` thing before binding, i don't know how that affect it? but when i did this  `$this->bind(':start_date', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_start)));
            $this->bind(':end_date', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_end)));` it worked. and i also remove the CAST (), so my query look like this `AND date_visited
                      BETWEEN :start_date
                      AND :end_date` please give that as an answer. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment you can use this code:

```
$date_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date));
$date_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_end));
```

To convert your variable contents to a format which MySQL needs

Now when you say that you have done it before and it was not working, I assume somewhere between this conversion and binding them to the `sql statement` you where changing them in your code, so either you can convert them immediately before binding them or as you suggested just convert them in the bind like this:

```
$this->bind(':start_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)));
```

And then your query will look like this

```
$this->sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS number_of_items FROM item_table
                      WHERE id > :id AND date_visited
                      BETWEEN :start_date
                      AND :end_date";
```

So to sum everything up, you can use one of these two ways. either of them should work, but you can use any of them you are more comfortable with:

**1. Convert the variables before binding them**

```
$date_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date));
$date_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_end));

$this->sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS number_of_items FROM item_table
                      WHERE id > :id AND date_visited
                      BETWEEN :start_date
                      AND :end_date";
$this->prepare($this->sql);
$this->bind(':id', 0);
$this->bind(':start_date', $date_start);
$this->bind(':end_date', $date_end);
// rest of your code
```

**2. Convert the variables during binding**

```
$this->sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS number_of_items FROM item_table
                      WHERE id > :id AND date_visited
                      BETWEEN :start_date
                      AND :end_date";
$this->prepare($this->sql);
$this->bind(':id', 0);
$this->bind(':start_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)));
$this->bind(':end_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_end)););
// rest of your code
```